# C3js Quit curve on data point with zero value

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

i have a graph when set the zero values don't show the dots, but if it have values then it show

[the graph look like this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3i_LHuXTynabVpiU1RQdF9OakE)

the issue is that i want to quit the curve only when show zero values and set a flat line only in that part
it is possible?

the code that i use for hide the dots

```
var circles = d3.selectAll('.c3-circle')
    circles
      .attr('visibility', function (d) {
        if (d.value === 0) {
          return 'hidden'
        }
      })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the spline type from the default 'cardinal' to 'monotone' - a type of curve segment that doesn't go above or below either of the two points it's connecting

At the moment this can only be done through the c3 internal object; so after you've loaded the c3 script and before you generate your chart add this line:

```
c3.chart.internal.fn.additionalConfig.spline_interpolation_type = 'monotone';
```

See this fiddle I've forked for an example with the change (comment it out and re-run to see the difference):

https://jsfiddle.net/752pxyu4/1/

Comment: btw there are some way to hide the points with C3 methods as well?
because as can you see i set up this with D3

Comment: From the reference it seems showing points through c3 is an all or nothing choice: http://c3js.org/reference.html#point-show , so your d3 solution looks like the best route

Comment: There is also the connectNull option if you don't even want to show a flat line: http://c3js.org/reference.html#line-connectNull - but that requires your zero data points to be 'null's - and it can look a bit weird when there's a lot of interruptions (lots of scattered nulls) in your data set